# C# WinForms UNDO (CRTL-Z) not working when PASTING text which adds Scroll Bars

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added a `TextChanged` function to allow AutoScroll behavior for a TextBox, 
it works fine and shortcuts working, except the UNDO (CTRL-Z) does not work when I have pasted text that is bigger than TextBox size.

It seems its because the ScrollBars appear and then for some reason the program does not have the past action (the PASTE) in the clipboard or something of this nature.

Is there something I need to change in this function? Or do I need to find a way to iterate thru events on ClipBoard (if that is even possible) I have posted the Function that I use to create the AutoScroll effect (found here on SO). Thanks for help

```
void TextBoxClass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Size textBoxRect = System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(
        this.Text, this.Font, new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, int.MaxValue),
        System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
    try
    {
        if (textBoxRect.Height > this.Height)
        {
            this.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
            // I ADDED below line to make it stay scrolled to bottom..
            // ..when the scrollBars appear
            this.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        else
            this.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None;
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
    {
        // this sometimes throws "failure to create window handle" error
        // This might happen if the TextBox is unvisible and/or
        // too small to display a toolbar.
    }
}
```

Comment: in textbox add properties KeyPreview true

Comment: This is normal.  Assigning the Scrollbars property forces Winforms to recreate the native control from scratch.  Underlying .NET method is Control.RecreateHandle().  Something that's visible when you pay close attention, you'll see the textbox flicker for a fraction of a second.  It has more side-effects beyond the flicker, yes, the undo buffer content is lost.  No simple workaround for this, you can't restore the undo buffer.

Comment: @ Kutty 
Cant find this property in TextBox. I found it for the Form and set it to true but didnt change anything.

Comment: @Hans . Thanks for the info. I guess i will try setting a string in the KeyDown Event to hold the text and then recreate the Undo if CTRL-Z is pressed

Comment: Have you considered using RichTextBox? It should have that functionality built in